# Log each request in ZF2

Tags: php, logging, zend-framework2, zend-log

We are using zend framework 2 for a new application, i would like to have the same logging system of Rails or similar, i would like have a log for each request, is possible to do this in Zend?

Comment: Why not use Apache's access_log?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends *what* you want to log. If it is just an access log, you should try to use the webserver's log. The logs from Apache/nginx/IIS etc perform better than you will achieve in your ZF2 app.

If you need to log inside the ZF2 application, you have two choices. First option is at `bootstrap`. It's one of the earliest options you can use, so probably therefore the best. However, you can also look at `route` or `dispatch`. Those two events are called during the "run" phase of the application. With these events, you have for example a route match available and therefore you know (or not) if your request did match any controller (or in case you don't have the match, it's a 404).

Some examples. Let's assume you have a logger configured in the `ServiceManager` under the `logger` key. Then to log at `bootstrap`:

```
namespace Application;

class Module
{
  public function onBootstrap($e)
  {
    $app = $e->getApplication();
    $sm  = $app->getServiceManager();

    $logger = $sm->get('logger');
    $logger->debug('Log here!');
  }
}
```

Or for example if you wait for `route`, you attach a listener for the `route` event:

```
namespace Application;

use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
use Zend\Mvc\Router\RouteMatch;

class Module
{
  public function onBootstrap($e)
  {
    $app = $e->getApplication();
    $em  = $app->getEventManager();
    $sm  = $app->getServiceManager();

    $logger = $sm->get('logger');
    $em->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, function($e) use ($logger) {
      $match = $e->getRouteMatch();

      // No route, this is a 404
      if (!$match instanceof RouteMatch) {
        return;
      }

      $logger->debug(sprintf(
        'Route event with route %s',
        $match->getMatchedRouteName()
      ));
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, as usual, Jurian. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you could attach a listener to the `dispatch` event on `Zend\Mvc\Application`.

For reference, Rob Allen has created a handy list of [ZF2 events](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/a-list-of-zf2-events/).